# NPE crash when recyclerview adapter creates callback interface to server

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the following custom onBindViewHolder method -

```
 @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull InstantVideoViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Video model) {
        boolean isWinner = checkIsWinner(model);
        holder.populate(model, this.getRef(position).getKey(), isWinner);
        Timber.d("onBindViewHolder: %s", holder.getTag());

        // resume active if needed
        if (position == getActivePos()) {
            markActiveVH(holder);
        }

    }
```

at holder.populate() method is where I instansiate all of my Video model variables, including callback objects. My view holder class implemets the callback interface and it's methods so inside the view holder I set the listeners by applying `this`.

here is my populate() method -

```
public void populate(Video video, String videoUid, boolean isWinner) {
        // load models
        mVideo = video;
        mVideoKey = videoUid;
        mContestKey = video.getContestId();
        mPresenter.setArgs(videoUid, true, true);
        setupDetailsView();

        // init viewcounts
        mViewStatsFinder = new DBViewStatsFinder(mContestKey, mVideoKey);
        mViewStatsFinder.setListener(viewCountsListener);
        mViewStatsFinder.findViewsCount();

        // info of owner
        ImageUtil.loadImageUrl(video.getProfile().getPhotoUrl(), imageViewOwner);
        tvOwner.setText(video.getProfile().getName());
//        tvPublishedDate.setText(video.getFormattedPublishDate());
//        tvContestInfo.setText(getFormattedContest(video));

        // video title
        mSongNameTv.setText(mVideo.getSongName());

        // contest number
        mContestNumber.setText( mVideo.getFormattedContestTitle(getContext()).replace("1MD Indian Talent ", ""));

        // winner
        tvOwner.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), isWinner ? R.color.gold_win : R.color.black));
//        tvPublishedDate.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), isWinner ? R.color.gold_win : R.color.black));
        imWinner.setVisibility(isWinner ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        // download
        mImageCover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ImageUtil.loadFirebaseImageUri(video.getThumbUri(), mImageCover);
        loadMediaSource();

        // subscribe if ready
        initDBEvents();
        subscribe();

        toggleCommentsLoadProgressbar(true);
        toggleVotesLoadProgressbar(true);
        toggleViewCountsProgressbar(true);
    }
```

my issue is that for some users, when the internet connection is slow, they crash while scrolling down the list - the view was clicked, and sends a callback to the server that might take some time. In that time the user might scroll down the list, and when the result comes back it comes to a null object because the relevant list item has already been recycled, meaning it is now null.

I was thinking of moving the entire holder.populate method to onCreateViewHolder but the issue is that the populate() method requires some parametrs which I can't get on the onCreateView().

Any ideas would be really helpfull.

edit -

here is my stack trace -

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.onemdtalent.app.presenters.sharelanding.ShareLandingPresenter$IVideoLikeSuccess.onLikeSuccess()' on a null object reference
com.onemdtalent.app.presenters.sharelanding.ShareLandingPresenter.completeUpdateVote (ShareLandingPresenter.java:455)
com.onemdtalent.app.presenters.sharelanding.ShareLandingPresenter.lambda$processVoteVideo$4 (ShareLandingPresenter.java:449)
com.onemdtalent.app.presenters.sharelanding.-$$Lambda$ShareLandingPresenter$F7TrCfo8uo_HGe9BlaEqncdfi1w.onComplete (Unknown Source:2)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run (Unknown Source:4)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6692)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

here is the corresponding code to the trace -

```
private void processVoteVideo(boolean liked) {
            // check vote to see if user has already voted. if so, check to see if user has liked. if liked - return. else - add like. if user has not voted, the like is processed as a vote. *orit*
            DataSnapshot snapshot = getExistVote();
            if (snapshot != null) {
                Vote vote = snapshot.getValue(Vote.class);
                if (vote != null) {
                    // close if already matched
                    if (vote.isLiked() == liked) {
                        getView().close();
                        //toggle like - if liked to unlike and vice versa

                    } else {

                        snapshot.getRef().setValue(vote, (DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) -> {
                            completeUpdateVote(databaseError == null);
                        });
                    }
                    completeUpdateVote(false);
                    return;
                }
            }
            VotesDBHelper.addVote(getUid(), mProfile, mVideo.getContestId(), mVideo.getContestStageKey(), mVideoKey, liked).addOnCompleteListener(task -> { //todo task was once called multiple times!! check why.
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Timber.v("Success likeVideo");
                } else {
                    Timber.w(task.getException(), "Error processLikeVideo");
                }
                completeUpdateVote(task.isSuccessful());
            });
    }

    private void completeUpdateVote(boolean successful) {
        if (successful) {
            mIVideoLikeSuccessListener.onLikeSuccess(); // --> here is the crash, the listener is null when receving the callback from the server because the list item has been recycled faster than the callback arriving. 
        } else {
            mIVideoLikeSuccessListener.onLikeFail();
        }
    }
```

the following code is my presenter ^.

Comment: show the exception stacktrace

Comment: I added the stacktrace from firebase crashlytics, I myself can't reproduct the bug

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko if you find anything helpfull I would be happy to hear

Comment: Please add the corresponding code that is shown in stacktrace

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko added the correspoding presenter code, please take a look.

Comment: I think what you are doing (calling api in `onBindViewHolder`) is bad practice...

Comment: @SaeedEntezari that is what I was sayed initially, therefore I would be happy to get any help of how to implement API calls in  `onCreateViewHolder()`  .

Comment: the easiest way would be just to check `if(mIVideoLikeSuccessListener != null)` if you are sure that it happens only for items that are off screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I needed.

I passed in the constructor of the ViewHolder the instantiation of the relevent API callback and then it was created only in onViewCreated so this was what I was looking for.

Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the whole code for you but I will show you a better way (imo) to do it:

The Idea is to move api calls out of the hands of RecyclerView or it's Adapter. The view-model or presenter should be responsible for it. so:

1. First add a [scroll listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addonscrolllistener) to your view-model( or Activity) which contains the recyclerview:

   `recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(...);`
2. Next in the scroll listener in the method `onScrollStateChanged` you check if the `newState` argument is equal to [`RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scroll_state_idle)
3. If yes then you need to find the first completely visible item by calling [`LinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findfirstcompletelyvisibleitemposition)
4. Now you have the index of the visible Item and you can get the information you need from the item in the list and load the video

**Note:** You need to check for [`RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scroll_state_dragging) in the method I mentioned in step 2 and cancel the call to api respectively.